# Knuth-Morris-Pratt with Fuzzy String Matching

Tags: algorithm, string

Does anyone know or have any idea if the KMP algorithm for substring searching can be modified to find not exact matches but approximate ones?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [Bitap algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitap_algorithm).